# export image from a userfom

Tags: excel, vba

I have a panel control which shows images in a userform generated from charts in the sheet "chart". They depend from a combobox2 which has a "preview" button that shows the chart's image in full quality in a secondary userform.

What I've been trying to do is make an export button for the user to be able to download the imnage to their PC (since the workbook is in a shared folder) by choosing the path. 
   BUT the issue comes in the image that I'm trying to export. I need a way to get the active picture in the image2 (that is in the second userform) so the user can download it.

Here is what I have up to now, but I get "nothing" from the `Set oChart`, iIneed to fill it somehow with the selected image

```
Function GetFolder1() As String

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim sitem As String

    Set oChart = Image2.Picture        

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode

        GetFolder1 = .SelectedItems(1)

     oChart.Export Filename:=GetFolder1 & ("\") & ComboBox2.Text & (".bmp")
    End With

NextCode:

    Set fldr = Nothing       
End Function
```

(got this code from this webpage)
thnx!

Comment: You can't assign a picture to a chart: you first need to create an empty chart, then paste the picture into it, then export the chart.

Comment: but, if i got the img in a location such as  "preview.image2.picture", why wouldnt it load?  it's telling me i have no object ....

Comment: How are you displaying your images on the user form? Are you using an image control or just setting the picture property of user form?

Comment: i'm using Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("Z:\Tesoreria\Documentos Compartidos\MACRO\Precisión Cash Flow (Débitos y Créditos).bmp"), (the chart previously got exported to that location and the name depends on the "combobox2")

Comment: If the image file is located in an accessible location then you could use VBA to copy the file to the user's local PC.

Comment: Hi Tim, how would you do that?, it's in an accesible location. i tried, and kinda failed XD. so if you got another way i'd love to see it!!!

Comment: `FileCopy sourcePath, destinationPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SavePicture` method. No need for Chart when you have the picture loaded in an Image control.

---

```
Public Sub SavePictureToDisk()

    Dim fldr As FileDialog

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode

        GetFolder1 = .SelectedItems(1)

      '/ Here save the ImageControl's picture to disk.
      SavePicture UserForm2.Image2.Picture, GetFolder1 & ("\") & comboBox2.Text & ".bmp"
    End With

NextCode:

    Set fldr = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: error in this line
 SavePicture UserForm2.Image2.Picture, GetFolder1 & ("\") & ComboBox2.Text & ".bmp"

Comment: `UserForm2.Image2` needs to be correct names of your userform and the image control on that form.

Comment: + if any1 uses this,    u gotta add the  dim getfolder1 as string